# Clause wait() : Process scheduling

Tags: c, linux

What is the difference between **wait(null)** and **wait(&status)** ?
When I have to use each of the them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
wait(&status);
```

allows you to get the termination status of the child process that exited. You would use this if you need to print a message that depends on how the child exited. You can get the code it passed to `exit()`, or the signal number if it was killed by a signal.

```
wait(null);
```

discards the termination status. You use it if you don't care why the child stopped.

Comment: And wait (null) returns the completed process PID, right ? 
Do I have to use either wait(Null)  or wait(&status)
I should not leave wait () without argument ?

Comment: Yes, they both return the PID. You can't call it with no arguments, functions always have to be called with the number of arguments in the declaration (C++ has function overloading that allows different signatures, but C doesn't).